# 'How to Create Hospital Management Systems in Python' from youtube - syntax error

Tags: python, class, tkinter, syntax-error

I'm trying to use the [How to Create Hospital Management Systems in Python - Full Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Na5HkZwiyaY) as a programming exercise to learn how to define classes. I've followed along making no changes but I get an error (in the video the script runs fine). I'm using Python 3.7.4 (64bit) in Windows 10.

```
# Import packages

from tkinker import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random
import time;
import datetime
import tkinter.messagebox

# Define interface 

class Hospital:

    def__init__(self, root):
        self.root = root 
        self.root.title("Hospital Management Systems") 
        self.root.geometry("1350x750+0+0") 
        self.root.configure(background='powder blue')  

        cmbNameTablets = StringVar()    
        Ref = StringVar()
        Dose = StringVar()
        NumberTablets = StringVar()
        Lot = StringVar()
        IssuedDate = StringVar()
        ExpDate = StringVar()
        DailyDose = StringVar()
        PossibleSideEffects = StringVar()
        FurtherInformation = StringVar()
        StorageAdvice = StringVar()
        DrivingUsingMachines = StringVar()
        HowtoUseMedication = StringVar()
        PatientID = StringVar()
        PatientNHSNo = StringVar()
        PatientName = StringVar()
        DateOfBirth = StringVar()
        PatientAddress = StringVar()
        Prescription = StringVar()

        MainFrame = Frame(self.root) 
        MainFrame.grid()

        TitleFrame = Frame(MainFrame, bd = 20, width = 1350, padx = 20, relief = RIDGE) 
        TitleFrame.pack(side = TOP)

        self.lblTitle = Label(TitleFrame, font = ('arial', 40, 'bold'), text = "Hospital Management Systems", padx = 2)   
        self.lblTitle.grid()     

        FrameDetail = Frame(MainFrame, bd = 20, width = 1350, height = 500, padx = 20, relief = RIDGE) 
        FrameDetail.pack(side = BOTTOM)


if__name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    application = Hospital(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Error message and traceback:

```
 File "<ipython-input-7-e64c65d6c91e>", line 3
    def__init__(self, root):
                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I expected it to look like it does at 10:36 in the video (a rather bare graphical interface).

I'm new to python and I've never defined classes before so I'm lost. Has the syntax changed since the video was made (August 2018), or is it because the instructor is using a different operating system/version of python?

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: error message and traceback added

Comment: Please always add the full error message, including the traceback to your question. That saves everyone a lot of guesswork. If the code you pasted here is an accurate copy of what you are trying to run, then you are just missing a space between `def` and `__init__` as well as `if` and `__name__` respectively.

Comment: Four typos: **1.** `from tkinker import *` **2.** `import time;` **3.** `def__init__(self, root):` **4.** `if__name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: make your example as minimal as possible please. Probably you're missing the space between def and __init__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1

Near the top of your source code:

```
from tkinker import *
```

You misspelled `tkinter` as `tkinker` with a `k`

## 2

Remove semi-colon from the line `import time;`

## 3

Put a space between `def` and `__init__` in `def__init__`

## 4

Put a space between `if` and `__name__` in `if__name__`